# What is the name of this moveable multiselect list?

Tags: terminology, html, controls, multi-selection

This is killing me. I am trying to find out what is the name of this UI component that has two multiselect controls, where the left is a list of available items and the right is the list of selected items, with some buttons for moving in-between.

[image: movable multiselect list]

I have a need for a rather large list of available selections and the user needs to also be able to see those selections. I am open to alternative components that can accomplish the same goal, but since the number of items selected will be rather large, the "tag" approach seen with multiselect components like [react-select](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) are not optimal.

Comment: I don't know know if there is an actual name for this, but I would think it could be "described" as a split pane combo/listbox. At the end of the day, it's just 2 comboboxes, the rest is just functionality.

Comment: @GrahamHerrli: this question has been asked many many times. I don't think that specific answer is correct, though. At least, in 2 decades I have never heard of "List Builder" but have heard of *multiple select*, *dual combo boxes*, *Multiselect*, *combo select* and other similar names. I'm pretty sure if you say "List builder" to anyone not reading that page at that exact time won't have any idea what are you talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### What names are there?

Microsoft calls this a [List Builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407.aspx#usage). As does the 2006 book '[Designing Interfaces](https://books.google.nl/books?id=oCTSeKfMaWUC&lpg=PA333&ots=mnj9e_OZUC&dq=ISBN%20978-0-596-00803-1&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q&f=false)' by O'Reilly.

Google calls this in Material Design UI a ["transfer list" (or "shuttle")](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/).

OpenFaces (an AJAX based component library) calls this [TwoListSelection](http://openfaces.org/components/#TwoListSelection).

Virtuosoft has a couple variations on what they call [Dual Listbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/). Codeplex also has a version called [Picklist (Dual Listbox)](https://picklist.codeplex.com/). Geodan names their version pretty similar; it's called [Dual List Box](https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox) on Github.

Someone else named their implementation [Listswap](https://github.com/phedde/listSwap).

There are a bunch more online that have less catchy names such as [Moving Values Between Select Boxes](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/selectbox/), [Moving Items Between List Boxes](http://Moving%20Items%20between%20List%20Boxes%20Available:%20%20ASPxEditors%20Library%20%20ASPxHTMLEditor%20Suite%20%20ASPxPivotGrid%20Suite%20%20ASPxScheduler%20Suite%20%20ASPxSpellChecker%20%20ASPxTreeList%20Suite%20%20XtraReports%20Suite%20%20XtraCharts%20Suite%20%20Add%20%3E%20Add%20All%20%3E%3E%20%3C%20Remove%20%3C%3C%20Remove%20All%20Chosen:%20%20ASPxperience%20Suite%20%20ASPxGridView%20and%20Editors%20Suite%20%20ASPxGauges%20Suite) and [Item Swapping from ListBoxes](https://codeworldtechnology.wordpress.com/tag/add-items-to-listbox-using-jquery/). These aren't object names, but article titles.

### Which is most used?

Microsoft and O'Reilly are a pretty well known companies so they seem a good starting point. But while googling the term *"list builder"* gives a whopping ~475.000 results, many are not what we are looking for. Many link to email/marketing tools such as signup sheets for news letters (grow your client list) or adding content (a list of concerts for a band).

"TwoListSelection" gets ~2000 hits without a lot of irrelevant links. But, many of these link (in)directly back to OpenFaces, so it's mostly based on just them.

Googling the terms *"Dual List Box"* and *"Double List Box"* gives ~3000 and ~6000 hits, which isn't a whole lot... but most (all?) of those actually link to appropriate content. Different implementations of this GUI element in HTML, Perl, VB2008 and so on.

Listswap gets about ~29.000 hits, but again many false positives. The majority of these are not about swapping items between two lists, but swapping places of items within a single list. "Apple, Bacon, Cheddar." becomes "Apple, Cheddar, Bacon."; not quite what we want.

### My Pick: Dual Listbox

Though it might not have the most hits, it has the 'most' hits without having to sort through a lot of unwanted results. It's also got some traction in different languages, as well as being used by several sources. This makes it a pretty healthy choice; not too dependent on a single organization and easy enough to find.

Comment: Material UI, not Google, calls it a transfer list. You can observe that searching [site:material.io "transfer list"] returns no result.

Answer (score 0):

It was also called as the Accumulator control and more technically as a List Builder